# How to use placeholder inside brackets in python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

Today I was wondering about the limitations of python formatting of strings. For example, say you want to build this kind of string : `${SOME_APPLICATION_VAR}`

If `SOME_APPLICATION_VAR` is not known in advance, how would you build this string ?

I tried `"${{}}".format(variable_name)` but it yields `${}`. I understand why but I can't find a way to achieve my goal. A lot of attempts were awarded with  exceptions.

Could someone give me some clues about how to do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use 3 of each bracket. 2 get resolved into a literal set of brackets, and the last set acts as the placeholder for the formatting.

```
print("${{{}}}".format(variable_name))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! It seems logic now that I know it, but it wasn't logic to me 20 minutes ago. Is it supposed to be intuitive ?

Comment: @AlexandreBonnetain I will say, this is one of my few complaints with Python. The new format strings coming in 3.6 are supposed to help, but yeah, it's weird.